# Refactoring needed for repetitious switch statements

Tags: c++, refactoring, switch-statement

The many repetitious switch statements seems like it needs to be DRY'd. Any suggestions? (Including doing nothing!)

```
AnimMapIter _iter;
    _iter = _animations->find(name);
    if(_iter == _animations->end()) return;

    if(_curName != name) {
        _curName = name;

        switch(dir) {
        case DIR_FORWARD_LOOPING: /* Fall through to DIR_FORWARD_NONLOOPING */
        case DIR_FORWARD_NONLOOPING:
            _iter->second->First();
            break;
        case DIR_REVERSE_LOOPING: /* Fall through to DIR_REVERSE_NONLOOPING */
        case DIR_REVERSE_NONLOOPING:
            _iter->second->Last();
            break;
        }
    } else {

        switch(dir) {
        case DIR_FORWARD_LOOPING: /* Fall through to DIR_FORWARD_NONLOOPING */
        case DIR_FORWARD_NONLOOPING:
            _iter->second->Next();
            break;
        case DIR_REVERSE_LOOPING: /* Fall through to DIR_REVERSE_NONLOOPING */
        case DIR_REVERSE_NONLOOPING:
            _iter->second->Previous();
            break;
        }

        switch(dir) {
            case DIR_FORWARD_LOOPING:
                if(_iter->second->IsAtEnd())
                    _iter->second->First();
                break;
            case DIR_FORWARD_NONLOOPING:
                if(_iter->second->IsAtEnd())
                    _iter->second->Last();
                break;
            case DIR_REVERSE_LOOPING:
                if(_iter->second->IsAtFront())
                    _iter->second->Last();
                break;
            case DIR_REVERSE_NONLOOPING:
                if(_iter->second->IsAtFront())
                    _iter->second->First();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like function pointers might help here.

Comment: Is this a good question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @jrok I was erring on the side of caution. If it needs to be moved, go ahead.

Comment: Whatever your class in `_iter->second` is, it looks like it's missing some interface. It feels all this switch statements could be replaced by some `Advance()` member function.

Comment: Everything under the `else` should collapse into a single `switch` to bring the related steps closer; e.g. for `case DIR_FORWARD_LOOPING:` do `_iter->second->Next(); if(_iter->second->IsAtEnd()) { _iter->second->First(); }` all in that one case.  Repetition of a couple of function calls is not a big deal when it makes the overall sequence of actions more clear.

Comment: @KevinGrant This is actually what I went with.

Comment: @KevinGrant Make your comment an answer an I'll accept it.

Comment: No problem - I added an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything under the else should collapse into a single switch to bring the related steps closer; e.g.

```
case DIR_FORWARD_LOOPING:
    _iter->second->Next();
    if (_iter->second->IsAtEnd()) {
        _iter->second->First();
    }
    break;
```

...all in that one case.  Repetition of a couple of function calls is not a big deal when it makes the overall sequence of actions more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Push the logic into whatever `_iter->second` is, along these lines (assuming the methods you've already shown exist):

```
class WhateverItIs
{
public:
   void Start() { if (m_forward) First(); else Last(); }
   void Stop()  { if (m_forward) Last(); else First(); }
   void Advance()
   {
      if (m_forward)
         Next();
      else
         Previous();
      if (IsLast())
      {
         if (m_loop)
            Start();
         else
            Stop();
      }
   }

private:
   bool IsLast() const
   {
      return m_forward ? IsAtEnd() : IsAtFront();
   }
   // Direction and looping are independent concepts.    
   bool m_forward;
   bool m_loop;
};
```

Then you can write:

```
AnimMapIter _iter;
_iter = _animations->find(name);
if(_iter == _animations->end()) return;

if(_curName != name) {
    _curName = name;
    _iter->second->Start();
} else {
    _iter->second->Advance();
}
```

---

Edit: Example using free functions and keeping the constants.

```
   void Start(Strip* s, bool forward) 
        { if (forward) s->First(); else s->Last(); }
   void Stop(Strip* s, bool forward) 
        { if (forward) s->Last() else s->First(); }
   void Advance(Strip* s, bool forward, bool loop)
   {
      if (forward)
         s->Next();
      else
         s->Previous();
      if (IsLast(s, forward))
      {
         if (loop)
            Start(s);
         else
            Stop(s);
      }
   }

   bool IsLast(const Strip* s, bool forward) const
   {
      return forward ? s->IsAtEnd() : s->IsAtFront();
   } 

   bool Projector::IsForward() const
   { 
       return dir == DIR_FORWARD_LOOPING || dir == DIR_FORWARD_NONLOOPING; 
   }

   bool Projector::IsLooping() const
   {
       return dir == DIR_REVERSE_LOOPING || dir == DIR_FORWARD_LOOPING;
   }

    if(_curName != name) {
        _curName = name;
        Start(_iter->second, IsForward());
    } else {
        Advance(_iter->second, IsForward(), IsLooping());
    }
```

Comment: The second parameter is a frame strip. Think of them as a strip of film. They themselves have no concept of forward or backward, just their first, last, and each of its frames. It's the film projector that runs the film in a particular direction.

Comment: @Casey: You can apply the same idea and have the methods (with the strip as parameter) in the controlling class. You can also have them as free functions. The DRYing is about abstracting the logic into functions. See edit.